# How to export values from the list of lists into a data frame?

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I have a very complicated structure, see pic below. I am struggling with this problem for a long time, and I really need help.

[image]

Here's the sample code to make my question more reproducible

```
t <- list(
list(answers = list(list(values = "male"),
                   list(values = "6"),
                   list(values = "9"),
                   list(values = "9"),
                   list(values = "other"))
 ),
list(answers = list(list(values = "145")
                  )
)
```

What I need are the values which are in the `answers` (from the each list).

I need this to look like a data frame — each list is the column (variable) and each value of the 1st list in `answers` is, obviously, value. Like this

```
> d <- data.frame("1" = "male", "2" = 6,
+                 "3" = 9, "4.1" = 9,
+                 "4.2" = 8,
+                 "5" = "other",
+                 "6" = 145)
> d

    X1 X2 X3 X4  X5   X6
1 male 6  9  9  other 145
```

The other issue is that values in the 1st list of `answers` **can contain multiple values**. And I really do not know how to deal with it as I need to assign variables their values accurately.

So, I cannot imagine how to get this. Intuitively, I think that `lapply()` may help me, but I do not know how to use it properly.

Comment: Please share a little bit of reproducible data - ideally `dput(test[1:3])` for the first 3 elements in a copy/pasteable data share.

Comment: @GregorThomas sorry, what should I do? I have not got your advice.

Comment: @GregorThomas if you want me to share this data here, I should say that I cannot do it. Some sensitive data contains in these lists.

Comment: Then you'll need to sanitize a small subset or generate a sample set of data.  Pictures of nested lists aren't sufficient to provide an answer.

Comment: I want you to share a little bit of sample data with the same structure as your real data. If you can't share `dput(test[1:3])`, perhaps you can either generate fake data with the same structure, or edit the sample data to remove / alter sensitive data points.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to generate the sample data some hours later. Please, do not leave my question! @GregorThomas

Comment: @GregorThomas I've made a sample code. May be you can still help me, please?

Comment: Please at least make your example at least length 2 and show the desired output for your sample input. Right now, half way through your question you show a sample output, and then at the bottom you show a sample input that seems pretty unrelated. Focus on making your question make sense - feel free to edit and delete things that are inconsistent (your entire edit history is saved a viewable by all - there's no need to flag things as *update* or *edit*).

Comment: @GregorThomas Okay, excuse me. Edited. I think that this way it is better.

Comment: This is looking much better, but the sample output doesn't correspond.The first list has strings like "male" (which is in the output) and "other" (which isn't). The second list doesn't. How should that be handled in the output? Where does the `22` in your output come from? Your output looks like you want one row per list item. How do you want to handle the length-2 sub-items like `c("9", "8")`? They could stay as a list, or they could be spread across multiple columns... we can do anything to them, but you should be the one to decided *what* to do.

Comment: Let's try again... @GregorThomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample data:

```
results = unlist(lapply(t, "[[", "answers"))
names(results) = paste0("X", seq_along(results))
results = as.data.frame(t(results))
#     X1 X2 X3 X4    X5  X6
# 1 male  6  9  9 other 145
```

The numbers are class `character` here, you may want to use `type.convert(results)` which will convert them to numerics (though it will also convert the remaining strings to `factor`s).

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one. Here are my thoughts. Also, not so helpful to not provide a `dput` of your data.

First I have to recreate a data set that resembles yours (extra work for me):

```
test <- list(
  list(
    answers = list(
      values = list("6", "8", "4", "11", "18"),
      question = list("some_text_1", "some_text_2", "some_text_3"))
    ),
  list(
    answers = list(
      values = list("male"),
      question = list("some_text_4", "some_text_5", "some_text_6"))
  )
  )
)
```

With some effort I can do this:

```
l1 <- lapply(test, function(x) lapply(x,`[[`, 1))
l2 <- unlist(l1, recursive = FALSE)
l3 <- unlist(l2, recursive = FALSE)
```

With this result:

```
> l3
$answers1
[1] "6"

$answers2
[1] "8"

$answers3
[1] "4"

$answers4
[1] "11"

$answers5
[1] "18"

$answers
[1] "male"
```

Or simpler:

```
unlist(l1)
```

But the latter looses structure and all `values` vectors end up as a single character vector.
In your list, I think this would give you all the `values` vectors at the 3rd nested level as a list with elements of unequal length. Because your `values` vectors have unequal length I would probably not try to coerce this to a data frame. Is this close enough?

**UPDATE**

With the update in the data set we can now do:

```
l1 <- lapply(t, `[[`, 1)
l2 <- unlist(l1, recursive = FALSE)
df <- as.data.frame(l2)
```

with this output:

```
> df
  values values.1 values.2 values.3 values.4 values.5
1   male        6        9        9    other      145
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But your code does not work properly. I know, this is my fault not providing an example data. Yours extra work does not reproduce the accurate data structure, though.

Comment: Btw, I've just edited my question with some sample code. It shows you the appropriate structure.

Comment: I updated my response as your data set is different from my original assumptions.